# How to stop Mixed Content error when making an AJAX request via Varnish/Nginx

Tags: ajax, nginx, https, varnish

I have a webpage (https://website.co.uk/blog/expertise/) running on HTTPS, some javascript (`XMLHttpRequest`) makes a request to an endpoint on the same domain (/ajax/articleindexlistingajax/loadmorearticles), which results in a Mixed Content error:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://website.co.uk/blog/expertise/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://website.co.uk/blog/expertise//ajax/articleindexlistingajax/loadmorearticles'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

- The site is using Varnish running on nginx/1.18.0, if I bypass Varnish, I don't get the error
- I've added ^ajax to the list of caching exclusions in the varnish `vcl_recv` and can see that it goes to the backend for this request

It's as if Varnish or Nginx is stripping the https but i'm completely out of ideas as to why.

Comment: The issue is in your AJAX call, you are making a call to `http://website.co.uk/blog/expertise//ajax/articleindexlistingajax/loadmorearticles` which is not `https`

Comment: The call is actually to the relative `/ajax/articleindexlistingajax/loadmorearticles` so it picks up https, also this works when bypassing varnish, but what comes back to the browser seems is http

Comment: Getting 404 on that link at the moment

Comment: That's not the real website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the base URL needs changing.

Looking at the error message above, the address it's complaining about is `http://website.co.uk/blog/expertise//ajax/...`.  The double slash looks like a concat somewhere, so my guess is it's concatenating your relative `/ajax/...` path onto the base URL `http://website.co.uk/blog/expertise/`.  If you can find where it's getting that base URL from, change it to use HTTPS, and probably remove the trailing slash, like `https://website.co.uk/blog/expertise`.

Base URLs are often defined in settings of site builders so the site knows how to construct revisit or redirection URLs.  Often sites are behind proxies, and SSL is usually terminated way before they see the request, so it is not obvious what the external URL really looked like without pre-configuring the static part of it.

Comment: The double slash is actually a type where i've attempted to obscure the real website.

It seem the error is being caused by the fact that Varnish is adding a Location header of: `http://website.co.uk/blog/expertise/ajax/articleindexlistingajax/loadmorearticles`

I've tried changing it to https but it attempts to use it as a place to redirect to, creating a redirect look.

If I remove the header altogether I get a `permanently moved` response

Comment: Ah, OK.  In that case, it's an absolute redirect that is being generated as `http://` for the same reason that SSL has already been terminated.  If it's coming from NGINX, you can fix it by adding `proxy_redirect http:// https://;` to your `server` block (or affected `location`s).  If it's coming from Varnish it's likely to be clear in your `vcl_recv` so I doubt it's there, but check anyway.

Comment: Amazing suggestion! I did a little reading around and the NGINX docs suggest `proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;` That seems to have done the trick. I'm just checking it's not affected anything else.